# 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in Interop.ZKFPEngXControl.dll (0x80040202)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sdk, fingerprint

I am developing a winform fingerprint reader application using ZKFinger SDK.
When i am running following code:

```
ZKFPEngXClass obj = new ZKFPEngXClass();
obj.OnImageReceived += Obj_OnImageReceived;
obj.OnCapture += Obj_OnCapture;
obj.OnEnroll += Obj_OnEnroll;
obj.OnFeatureInfo += Obj_OnFeatureInfo;
```

then i get error on

```
 obj.OnCapture += Obj_OnCapture;
 obj.OnEnroll += Obj_OnEnroll;
 obj.OnFeatureInfo += Obj_OnFeatureInfo;
```

but

```
obj.OnImageReceived += Obj_OnImageReceived;
```

works fine.

Error is

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   Interop.ZKFPEngXControl.dll".
>  Additional information: Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80040202

Answer (score 0):

You should register those events only after you connect to the device.

```
        if (objCZKEM.Connect_Net(IPAdd, Port))
        {
            //65535 or 32767- depends
            if (objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 32767))
            {
                // [ Register your events here ]
                // [ Go through the _IZKEMEvents_Event class for a Ex);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: I am using  obj.InitEngine() to initialize device and it returns "initialize successfull" and it is a usb device.

Comment: Ok,  But to use those events, make sure to register them. 65535 or 32767  using the RegEvent method generally works for registering all the events.

Comment: In this code first event works fine but  next gives errors. For example, if i comment "obj.OnImageReceived += Obj_OnImageReceived;" then " obj.OnCapture += Obj_OnCapture;" works fine but others gives error. I don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
ZKFPEngXClass obj = new ZKFPEngXClass();
```

use

```
ZKFPEngXControl.ZKFPEngX obj = new ZKFPEngXControl.ZKFPEngX();
```

Hope it helps.